# Android limitation or Device Incapability?

Tags: support, profile-page, mobile-web

While accessing Stack Overflow from my Android phone, I've noticed that some elements on my home page are missing (flag history, etc). With more astonishment, I noticed there is no option to edit my bio. Is it not possible to edit bio while accessing Stack Overflow from Android, or is it a little known device problem? I am using LG Optimus L5 with Android ICS. Would someone help me to understand what is going on? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These pages are simply not available in the mobile version of the site. You *can* access them on your mobile device by switching to the full site (via the link at the very bottom). It has nothing to do with Android or your specific phone.

Comment: Thank you very much for you quick response. Now I got the solution.